# <input type="text"> simply ignore flex-grow: 1

Tags: html, css

Please see this minimum example

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="text">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;

  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
  border: 1px solid red;

  input {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }

  div {
    min-width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
}
```

And the result

[image]

Why is this happening?

Does `<input type="text" />` has minimum width or something?

But I can't find it, and explicitly set `width` went back to normal.

Comment: can you update your post with snippet ?

Comment: I have html and css, what snippet do you mean?

Comment: min-width:0 to input